# Optimization cannot be performed error when trying to get sales price for specific item in acumatica

Tags: rest, api, acumatica, endpoint

I am trying to get sales price for specific item in acumatica.

By postman I sent GET request to this URL:

https://my-acumarica-url/entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesPricesInquiry/?$filter=InventoryID eq '1000004'

I got the following error:

```
{
"message": "An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage": "Optimization cannot be performed.The following fields cause the error:\r\nEffectiveAsOf: View Filter has BQL delegate\r\nPriceWorkgroupIsMine: View Filter has BQL delegate\r\nInventoryID: View Filter has BQL delegate\r\nItemClassID: View Filter has BQL delegate\r\nPriceClass: View Filter has BQL delegate\r\nPriceCode: View Filter has BQL delegate\r\nPriceManager: View Filter has BQL delegate\r\nPriceManagerIsMe: View Filter has BQL delegate\r\nPriceType: View Filter has BQL delegate\r\nPriceWorkgroup: View Filter has BQL delegate\r\n",
"exceptionType": "PX.Api.ContractBased.OptimizedExport.CannotOptimizeException",
"stackTrace": "   at PX.Api.ContractBased.OptimizedExport.NotWorkingOptimizedExportProvider.get_CanOptimize()\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetList(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, Boolean returnFullEntities, CbOperationContext operationContext, Boolean ignoreValueFields, PXGraph graph)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapFacadeBase.GetListImpl(Entity entity, Boolean returnFullEntities)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.RestController.GetList(String objectName, String select, String filter, String expand, String custom, Nullable`1 skip, Nullable`1 top)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SalesPricesInquiry` is an inquiry and should be accessed via `PUT`, as the [documentation says](https://help.acumatica.com/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=6340cff3-4732-4231-9e42-5d1e5e65b5dd).

Comment: Thanks! Your link pulls up the front-page of the documentation, not the page showing the SalesPricesInquiry information. The "Web Services Endpoints" have some documentation, but not enough (like should PUT/GET be used). A website link that details all the inquiries and their options/parameters would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

According to Default/17.200.001/swagger.json

```
"/InventorySummaryInquiry": {
 "put": {
    "tags": [
      "InventorySummaryInquiry"
    ],
    "summary": "Creates a record or updates an existing record.",
    "operationId": "InventorySummaryInquiry_PutEntity",
    "consumes": [
      "application/json",
      "text/json"
    ],
    "produces": [
      "application/json",
      "text/json"
    ],
```

A "PUT" will cause an inventory entry to be created.

When I "PUT" Default/17.200.001/InventorySummaryInquiry

```
 {"WarehouseID" : {"Value":"MSE01"}}
```

I get in response

```
{
  "id": "497b52a8-8a81-4345-bcaa-9b607231886b",
  "rowNumber": 1,
  "note": null,
  "ExpandByLotSerialNbr": {},
  "InventoryID": {},
  "LocationID": {},
  "WarehouseID": {},
  "custom": {},
  "files": []
}
```

which does not make sense to me. I have 2000+ items in the "MSE01" warehouse.

I get a new "id" each time I try this, which maybe means a new entry is getting created, and that's what's being returned?

Comment: Swagger documentation is incorrect. Since this is an inquiry form on Acumatica, then using it through the API requires a PUT, since that's what Acumatica does internally to get the data. In my Acumatica for the query, the ProductID is required, so I can't just leave it blank and hope to get a list of all items. - To get a true inventory list I will have to create a Generic Inquiry and figure out how to make it REST API accessible.

Comment: If put is for retrieving data, then what to use to insert into the inquiry?